# Get text from NDEF message received over NFC

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p

I need some help in handling data which was received by NFC. I'm using [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814814/Android-Connectivity#nfc) to receive an NDEF message over NFC and display the text contained in the NDEF record in a toast.

Now I want to fill the received data into an `EditText` field. Right now it just shows the received data for a while (as a toast). I've tried to change the code, but I wasn't successful:

```
void parseNdefMessage(Intent intent) {
    Parcelable[] ndefMessageArray = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
            NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = (NdefMessage) ndefMessageArray[0];
    Toast.makeText(this, new String(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(
        getApplicationContext(),"Here is my text", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    editText.getText().toString().equals(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload()[0]);
    //editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    //String text = editText.getText().toString();
    editText.setText(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload()[0]); //my attempt to set my received data to "editText" field
}
```

Could anyone give some advice about this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the data changed: why dont you try:

```
void parseNdefMessage(Intent intent) {
    Parcelable[] ndefMessageArray = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
            NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    NdefMessage ndefMessage = (NdefMessage) ndefMessageArray[0];
    String msg = new String(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload());
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Here is my text", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    //String text = editText.getText().toString();
    editText.setText(msg); //my attempt to set my received data to "editText" field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make much sense.

1. You use the `equals()` method on the string representation of the value of the `editText` field without checking the return value:

   ```
   editText.getText().toString().equals(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload()[0]);
   ```

   As the `equals()` method does not change the state of the object (and in fact you throw away that string object anyways), calling this method makes only sense if you check its return value (which would tell you if the string value in `editText` matches the value of `...getPayload()[0]`). However, as `getPayload()[0]` is a byte value, the `equals()` method will **always** return `false`. Hence, you can drop this line of code.
2. `ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload()[0]` gives you the first byte of the payload of that NDEF record. Thus, this is only the first character (or as you seem to use UTF-8 encoding possibly even only a part of the first character).
3. When you use the byte value `ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload()[0]` as parameter for the method `editText.setText(x)`, it will be treated as an integer indicating a resource ID. This does not make any sense.

So instead, you would want to convert the payload of the NDEF record into a string (using the default UTF-8 charset encoding):

```
String text = new String(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload());
```

You can then assign that string value to `editText`:

```
editText.setText(text);
```

This is just the same as you already do when setting the message of the toast:

```
Toast.makeText(this,
               new String(ndefMessage.getRecords()[0].getPayload()),   <--- HERE 
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```